# Is it possible to link Couchbase Gateway Sync to a Cloudant server?

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, cloudant

I am attempting to create a gateway between an android app running Couchbase Lite and a Cloudant database. Currently we are using Cloudant Sync on Android to link directly, but it is not available on iOS, so we are just sizing up options at the moment. Would be actually be possible to link  a Couchbase Gateway server to a Cloudant Database, or does Couchbase only sync with pure CouchDB Databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this posting, sync_gateway only works with couchbase products directly, out of the box and supported. The source is open though and you could modify it if you are so inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have switched now to CouchDB and this is able to continuously replicate directly to Cloudant, and it is working well.